# Docker Volume Binded with Container from Shared location

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to make a centralized location for postgresql data, and use that for multiple containers on the same network of docker. For this i have to use the shared location in the volume, for example something like

```
docker -v 0.0.0.0\data:/var/lib/postgrsql/data
```

How can i specify the shared location as volume's host path and make a linkage with the container's binded folder.

Environment details:

- Ubuntu 17.10
- Docker 17

Any help or guidance to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: without using any storage plugins, you have to mount the directory to all the nodes in the swarm; then, mount the host directory inside containers using volumes; i.e. `docker run -v "/location/on/host:/var/lib/postgrsql/data"`

Comment: so, you are saying that i have to mount it on my host machine ?

Comment: yes, the directory must be accesible to all the nodes; docker does not have a builtin solution AFAIK that shares a directory across all the nodes in the swarm; there are other solutions, outside docker; one is `nfs`, the simplest.

Comment: Okay, can you point me to a direction, where i can use that directly ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-postgres-hot-standby

Comment: https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container/tree/master/examples/replica

Answer (score 0):

In Swarm you want to use a volume driver. This way 1. you don't have manual nfs mounts on each node host OS, and 2. you can ensure that the volume you want for a specific service is connected to the host it plans to run on.

The [Docker Store has a list of volume plugin drivers](https://store.docker.com/search?category=volume&q=&type=plugin) for various storage solutions.

If you're using cloud storage or simple NFS, [REX-Ray is likely the plugin you want](https://rexray.io/).